# Connecting to MySQL in another file is not recognized

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, database-connection

I want to connect to a MySQL database in PHP. I use this code:

```
<?php
    function login($empID, $password)
    {
        $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
        if ($connection->connect_errno)
        {
            die ($connection->connect_error);
        }

        $result = $connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logins WHERE EmpID = " . $empID . ";");
        echo $result->fetch_row()[0];
        $connection->close();
    }
?>
```

This works perfectly fine. Thing is, I have to open and close the database in every file I need the DB, so I wanted to create the mysqli object in a separate file and call it when needed, something like:

```
<?php
    include_once('scripts/db_script.php');
    function login($empID, $password)
    {
        $connection = db_connect();

        $result = $connection->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Logins WHERE EmpID = " . $empID . ";");
        echo $result->fetch_row()[0];
        db_close();
    }
?>
```

with db_script that looks like this:

```
<?php
    function db_connect()
    {
        $connection = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
        if ($connection->connect_errno)
        {
            die ($connection->connect_error);
        }

        return $connection;
    }

    function db_close($connection)
    {
        $connection->close();
    }
?>
```

but when I do this, I got the fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in...
```

I guess there is a way to do what I would like to do, but I just not doing it correctly, so can someone explains me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: General rule of thumb: You connect ONCE to the database, at script startup (or at least before your first query), then re-use that connection for all of your db operations. Continually connecting/disconnecting is inefficient and break lots of functionality, such as transactions and session variables.

Comment: it is not HTML I am talking about but functions you posted here.

Comment: this code would produce a different error. So, it's evidently not the code you run.